# Can I use EntityFramework and sql azure with Sharepoint Online?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, sql, azure

I would like to connect to an entity model from a sandboxed webpart in sharepoint online. Is this possible?

Is it possible to connect to sql azure from a sandboxed webpart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two ways

1. Use BCS in SPO with a WCF endpoint to access data in SQL Azure leveraged through an external list
2. Use client side techs such as JavaScript or Silverlight

For an example with jQuery and JSONP check out: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-Online-and-External-Data-using-JSONP.aspx

Answer (score 0):

TIP: You'll need to be wary of cross site scripting if you do it client side, check out JSONP to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can combine SharePoint and Azure in a variety of ways. Have a look at the following training kit:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24398